# Installing R GitHub Package into a Specific Directory

Tags: r

Im trying to install an R package from Github using DevTools as so:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("jeffbhasin/goldmine")
install_github("jeffbhasin/methylaction")
```

Problem is, Im using a shared HPC and need to install the packages in a specific directory.  I tried doing the following but it didn't work:

```
install_github("jeffbhasin/goldmine", lib="/mydir")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please add the error that is thrown back?

Answer (score 0):

Using `?install_github` there is no `lib` argument. `subdir` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: That's not correct.  subdir changes the directory used on github.